# Force SDL_Window to be active/on top, making parent window inaccessible (like ShowDialog in WinForms)

Tags: c#, c++, sdl

I'm using SDL2 (specifically, a C# wrapper of SDL2 (SDL2-CS) but it has all the same features and functionality) and am trying to make a game editor with it. Everything's going really well, but there's one piece of functionality I'd really like. That's to make one specific window always appear on top of its parent window, while making the parent window inaccessible. When the window is minimized and you open it, it opens and focuses on the child window. When you try to access the parent window, it flickers and you hear a windows error message.

I know how to manually focus on a window, but I don't know how to make a sort of "link" like that between two windows, where window A is inaccessible until window B is closed.

I know the Windows Forms equivalent is Form.ShowDialog(). That's what I want, but currently the way it works is like Form.Show(). To clarify, I'm not using Windows Forms or any other library/framework. I'm using pure SDL2; this was just an example.

I'm looking to implement this using pure SDL2.

Comment: There is a [SDL_SetWindowModalFor](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowModalFor) function.

Comment: There is no cross-platform way to do this, so I doubt SDL have this functionality built in. Maybe you can catch all window events in the parent window and let that trigger giving focus back to the child window.